# Selectively turn off varioref labelformats

Tags: varioref

`varioref` introduces the command `\labelformat` which can automatically render `\ref{sec:...}` as `section~` etc. This feature is very useful for saving some typing and making everything flexible (especially when dealing with theorem environments that can change type).

However, occasionally you want to turn it off for one individual reference. For instance, I might want the last line in the below code to be rendered `The sections~1 and~2 tell the whole story.` But because of `\labelformat`, it becomes `The sections~section~1 and~section~section~2 tell the whole story.` **How can I turn labelformats off for individual references?**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varioref}

\labelformat{section}{section~#1}

\let\varref\ref %make me some other command \varref that omits "section"

\begin{document}
    \section{Once upon a time\ldots}\label{sec:once}

    There was a king.

    \section{And then\ldots}\label{sec:then}

    This was already told in \ref{sec:once}.

    \section{Conclusion}

    The sections~\varref{sec:once} and~\varref{sec:then} tell the whole story.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `cleveref` with `varioref` to do those things automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're abusing `varioref`. Use `cleveref` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Once upon a time\ldots}\label{sec:once}

There was a king.

\section{And then\ldots}\label{sec:then}

This was already told in \cref{sec:once}.

\section{Conclusion}

The \cref{sec:once,sec:then} tell the whole story.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I usually use the `memoir` class. Is `cleveref` still incompatible with `memoir`?

Comment: @Gaussler I see only one caveat about labels in subfloats, in the manual of `cleveref` (section 14.1, third bullet).